# Trying to plot graph in R using shiny , it is taking lot of time to load, data is somewhat 1 TB

Tags: r, graph, ggplot2, bigdata, shiny

I am trying to ploat a graph using ggplot. its asingle sales graph where x axis is year and y axis is sales in the particulat year using shiny framework in R. the input file contain dales detail for every day. Complete data size for  approx 1 TB. Graph is getting plotted but it is taking lot of time approx 5 mins. please suggest any solution for the same.

thanks in advance

Comment: `ggplot2` has flexibility, but not speed. Consider using an alternative graphinc device. Base graphics are faster. Alternatively, consider down-sampling the data and plot only a portion of it.

Comment: Or one of the smoothScatter/hexplot type options that bin data first.  Most plotting systems just plot each point without checking whether doing so is sane.  With 1TB of data, it's not sane :-)

Comment: Thanks Ari i'll try your suggestion.

Comment: Thanks Roman. it works fine for a portion of graph.

Answer (score 1):

You can buy Solid-state drive to get faster loading of data if R supports.